# Calculate most common values

Tags: matlab, count, matrix

If i have a matrix A with n values spanning from 65:90. How do i get the 10 most common values in A? I want the result to be a 10x2 matrix B with the 10 common values in the first column and the times it appears in the second column.

Answer (score 5):

```
A = [65 82 65 90; 90 70 72 82]; % Your data
range = 65:90;
res = [range; histc(A(:)', range)]'; % res has values in first column, counts in second.
```

Now all you’ve got to do is sort the `res` array by the second column and take the first 10 rows.

```
sortedres = sortrows(res, -2); % sort by second column, descending
first10 = sortedres(1:10, :)
```

Comment: You will want to use values(:) since A is a matrix and not neccessarily a vector.
Also, sortrows can easily be made to sort descending by using sortrows(res, -2) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved using arrayfun()

```
A = [...]; % Your target matrix with values 65:90
labels = 65:90 % Possible values to look for
nTimesOccured = arrayfun(@(x) sum(A(:) == x), labels);
[sorted sortidx] = sort(nTimesOccured, 'descend');

B = [labels(sortidx(1:10))' sorted(1:10)'];
```

Answer (score 1):

this can also be solved with accumarray

```
ncounts = accumarray(A(:),1);  %ncounts should now be a 90 x 1 vector of counts
[vals,sidx] = sort(ncounts,'descend');   %vals has the counts, sidx has the number
B = [sidx(1:10),vals(1:10)];
```

accumarray is not as fast as it should be, but often faster than other operations of its type. it took me a number of scans of its help page to understand what the hell it is doing. for your purposes, it is probably slower than the histc solution, but a little more straight-forward.

--edit: forgot the '1' in the accumarray call.

Comment: That is NOT the correct way to use **accumarray**! take a look at this video by *Doug Hull* which shows a typical usage of the function: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/10/02/basics-using-accumarray/

Comment: yes, I forgot the 1. however, this is the essence of accumarray. I think of it as the fast, well-defined way of doing output(idx) += vals. your comments notwithstanding, this is the correct way to use accumarray.

Answer (score 1):

We can add a fourth option using **tabulate** from the Statistics Toolbox:

```
A = randi([65 90], [1000 1]);   %# thousand random integers in the range 65:90
t = sortrows(tabulate(A), -2);  %# compute sorted frequency table
B = t(1:10, 1:2);               %# take the top 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Heck, here is another solution, all simple builtin commands

```
[V, I] = unique(sort(A(:)));
M = sortrows([V, diff([0; I])], -2);
Top10 = M(1:10, :);
```

First line: sorts all values, and then looks for the offset where each new values starts in the sorted list.
Second line: compute the offset differences per unique value, and sort those results.

*BTW, I would only suggest this method if the range possible numbers is really large, such as [0,1E8]. In that case, some of the other methods might get an out-of-memory error.*